# Finding SFML with CMake (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: opengl, cmake, sfml

I'm trying to get started with opengl. I have first followed a [tutorial](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Mesa-(OpenGL)-on-Linux-Mint) to install opengl, compiled their example it works fine. Then I installed the pre-requisite libraries suggested from [here](https://open.gl/introduction).

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglm-dev libsoil-dev libglew-dev libglew1.5-dev libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev libglfw3 libglfw3-dev libsfml-dev
```

I have then taken an [example](https://open.gl/content/code/c2_triangle_uniform.txt) from their website, and have tried to compile it using CMake. It fails at the `find_package` step

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

################
# Project
################ 
project (opengl_test)

################
# Packages
################
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
```

OpenGL and GLUT are found and linked correctly, and the files requiring only those two compile and run as expected. However, SFML finding does not work

```
  By not providing "FindSFML.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SFML", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" with any of
  the following names:

    SFMLConfig.cmake
    sfml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SFML_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SFML"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I suspect I have to provide a path to SFML. I am aware that there is about 30 posts about this same topic on StackOverflow. I have tried several of them, and they did not work, the error is still the same.

Comment: Is there an `SFMLConfig.cmake` somewhere in your `/usr` tree? libsfml-dev should have put one there.

Comment: Exactly. I managed to solve it using `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/share/SFML/cmake/Modules")`. I'm sure I tried it before like 10 times and it did not work. I need to get used to deleting temporary cmake files when debugging. But hey, it's solved now :)

Comment: A slightly cleaner approach is to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/share/SFML`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Eventually I want to make it platform-independent, perhaps using `find_path`, but for now it works, I should focus on actual program :D